# Quartz scheduler time setting - comma not accepted

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I'm trying to set a Quartz job to run every minute in every hour, except in 0 and 30 minutes.

When I try to configure like this:

```
ScheduledSenderJob=0 2-28 * * * ?
```

It works perfectly for me.
But when I try this:

```
ScheduledSenderJob=0 2-28,35-58 * * * ?
```

I got an Exception, when I launch Glassfish server: CronException, invalid character, . Somehow the comma character doesn't seem to work, and I couldn't work it out.

Could someone help me out, what the correct scheduling would be?
Thank you.

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: CronExpression '0 2-28' is invalid,.
at eu.pont.zf.szkif.sched.quartz.QuartzServicesImpl.startScheduling(QuartzServicesImpl.java:200)
at eu.pont.zf.szkif.sched.quartz.QuartzServicesImpl.init(QuartzServicesImpl.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:206)
... 48 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED:

Whatever software is providing you access to the ScheduledSenderJob property is interpreting the string and tokenizing on the commas. Below is an example app that loads your cron expression from a java properties file and runs without a problem:

```
import static org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;

    import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
    import org.quartz.Trigger;


    /**
     * Hello world!
     *
     */
    public class App 
    {

        public static void main( String[] args )
        {
             SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();

              Scheduler sched;
            try {
                sched = schedFact.getScheduler();

                Properties props = new Properties();
                InputStream inputStream = sched.getClass().getClassLoader()
                        .getResourceAsStream("test.properties");

                props.load(inputStream);

                String cronString = props.getProperty("cron");

                  // define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
                  JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class)
                      .withIdentity("myJob", "group1")
                      .build();

                System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
                Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
                        .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
                        .withSchedule(cronSchedule(cronString))
                        .forJob("myJob", "group1")
                        .build();

                sched.scheduleJob(job,trigger);
                sched.start();
            } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }
```

HelloJob.java:

```
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class HelloJob implements Job{

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Hello ! ");

    }

}
```

test.properties - I moved the timing bits to seconds to see the results faster.

```
cron=2-28,35-58 * * * * ?
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it doesn't seem to work. Now it has problem with the quotation marks:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.text.ParseException: Unexpected character: "

Comment: Where is the ScheduledSenderJob property located ? Is it in a standard Java properties file or is it coming from somewhere else ? I was able to create a very simple test app that loads that string from a property file, creates a cronTrigger and kicks off a job as expected. My guess is that the problem lies in the software that is handling the ScheduledSenderJob property for you. Its treating the comma as something special and tokenizing the string.

Comment: If putting quotes around the string allowed your software to get the full cron expression but with quote characters in it, then you could hack that and remove the quotes from the string before passing it to the cronSchedule constructor.

Comment: Hi Sinsanator, thank you for your help. All our scheduling informations are in a property file, and we have a plenty of scheduled jobs. Everything works perfectly fine except for this problem, so you might be right: the problem might be in the handling software.
We decided to use a workaround solution (the job is scheduled to run every minute and we handle the unnecessary minutes inside the job), but I think you completely deserve to be the solver of this topic.
Thank you again!

Comment: Thanks Igorovics, Im glad you found a solution!